# Which leads are abbreviated typically as channel ECG 1 and ECG 2?

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiography

I want make sure about the fact in the documentation of MIT-BIH NSRDB [here](https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/nsrdb/).
They just say ECG 1 and ECG 2 but not what particularly.

I think they are the frontal plane channel and transverse plane channel but in which order, I do not know.

In their other database (MIT-BIH Arr.), #1 Channel was about MLII, but #2 Channel about V1. 
So I am confused.

Normally, I get data which says leads are this and this. Display channels can be this and this. Etc with this [device](http://www.alwilmedical.com/_storage/assetmanager/file/UT6000A%20English.pdf), very clear manual.

Ticket: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/physionet/issues/21

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electrical schematics, not biology. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you just ask them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in the ticket but it is still little open because it does say which lead is ECG1 and which ECG2

> These records are from Holter recorders and the leads are not in
>   standard precordial positions. As a general rule one lead is
>   approximately a V5 position or a modified lead II (recording from
>   right pectoral area to the cardiac apex), and the other lead is
>   generally close to a V2 position.